# Is there a better way to compare two lists in Python, stopping at the shorter list?

Tags: python, list, zip

I'm trying to compare two lists with short-circuiting logic such that if one list is shorter than the other stop the comparison and return True. I'd like to know if what I have is sufficiently Pythonic or if there is a better way to do it.

```
def compareLists(list1,list2):
    # Comparison invalid if either list is empty
    if not list1 or not list2:
        return False

    equalList = True    # initialize as true
    for (l1,l2) in zip(list1,list2):
        if l1 != l2:
            equalList = False
            break
    return equalList
```

```
ipdb> list1 = [1,2,3]
ipdb> list2 = [1,2,3,4]    
ipdb> compareLists(list1,list2)
True
```

Comment: consider that it's not clear what "Pythonic" means. Do you mean "the most processing efficient way" or perhaps "the most memory efficient way" or some other measure of "best/most" - to help people answer your question faster

Comment: Why re-implement the comparison logic when what you describe is already the built-in logic of list comparisons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more pythonic way would be to use `all`:

```
def compare_lists(list1, list2):
    if not list1 or not list2:
        return False
    else:
        return all(x1 == x2 for x1, x2 in zip(list1, list2))
```

Also note that the naming convention in Python is not camel case, but snake case.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was on the wrong track when I had to initialize the answer and do a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop.  You can use the `min` function to get the length of the shorter list (L), then use the `==` operator to compare the first L elements of each list, like so:

```
def compareLists(list1, list2):
    L=min(len(list1), len(list2))
    return list1[:L]==list2[:L]
```

The following returns `True`:

```
lista=[1,3,4,6,7,8,4,6]
listb=[1,3,4,6,7,8,4,6,3,7,5,2,4]
print (compareLists(lista, listb))
```

Whereas, the following returns `False`:

```
lista=[1,3,4,6,7,-8,4,6]
listb=[1,3,4,6,7,8,4,6,3,7,5,2,4]
print (compareLists(lista, listb))
```

Comment: Thanks. This is better than my attempt, but I think I like the all() syntax above.